# Find the average of multiple columns for each distinct variable in column 1

Tags: linux, awk, sum, average, uniqueidentifier

Hi I have a file with 6 columns and I wish to know the average of three of these (columns 2,3,4) and the sum of the last two (columns 5 and 6) for each unique variable in column one.

```
A1234 0.526 0.123 0.456 0.986 1.123
A1234 0.423 0.256 0.397 0.876 0.999
A1234 0.645 0.321 0.402 0.903 1.101
A1234 0.555 0.155 0.406 0.888 1.009
B5678 0.111 0.345 0.285 0.888 0.789
B5678 0.221 0.215 0.305 0.768 0.987 
B5678 0.336 0.289 0.320 0.789 0.921
```

I have come across code that will get the average for column 2 based on column one but is there anyway I can expand this across columns? Thanks

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2; c[$1]++} END{for (i in a) printf "%d%s%.2f\n", i, OFS, a[i]/c[i]}'
```

I would like the output to be in the following format ;each variable in column one will also have a different number of rows

```
A1234 0.53725 0.21375 0.41525 3.653 4.232
B5678 0.22233 0.283 0.30333 2.445 2.697
```

Comment: what is the format of output ? I mean first is index(1st column) how about other fields? Could you please explain the same too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2;b[$1]+=$3;c[$1]+=$4;d[$1]+=$5;e[$1]+=$6;f[$1]++} END{for (i in a) print i,a[i]/f[i],b[i]/f[i],c[i]/f[i],d[i],e[i]}' file
```

O/p:

```
B5678 0.222667 0.283 0.303333 2.445 2.697
A1234 0.53725 0.21375 0.41525 3.653 4.232
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate average of column 2, 3, 4:

```
 awk '{ sum += $2 + $3 + $4 } END { print sum / (NR * 3) }'
```

To calculate the sum of column 5 and 6 group by column 1:

```
 awk '{ arr[$1] += $5 + $6 } END { for (a in arr) if (a) print a, arr[a] }'
```

<s>To calculate column 5 and 6 of the last row:</s>

```
 tail file -1 | awk '{sum += $5 + $6} END {print sum}'
```

Comment: It is not covering the index part of OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

try following once and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{A[$1]=A[$1]?A[$1]+$5+$6:$5+$6;C[$1]=C[$1]?C[$1]+$2+$3+$4:$2+$3+$4;B[$1]++} END{for(i in A){print "Avg. for " i" =\t",C[i]/(B[i]*3) RS "Count for " i" =\t",A[i]}}'  Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '{
        A[$1]=A[$1]?A[$1]+$5+$6:$5+$6;
        C[$1]=C[$1]?C[$1]+$2+$3+$4:$2+$3+$4;
        B[$1]++
     }
        END{
                for(i in A){
                                print "Avg. for " i" =\t",C[i]/(B[i]*3) RS "Count for " i" =\t",A[i]
                           }
           }
    '   Input_file
```

Comment: So that gives me the following output;

Comment: Avg. for B5678 =         0.269667
Count for B5678 =        5.142
Avg. for A1234 =         0.38875
Count for A1234 =        7.885

Comment: without showing us the expected results I could only guess, let us know which format you need because output looks accurate only, thing is only we may need to fine tune it as per your requirement now, let me know on same.

Comment: A1234 0.53725 0.21375 0.41525 3.653 4.232

Comment: honestly not sure still, it is not at all clear. It will be nice if you could edit your post with code tags. Also output looks little strange to me, only 1 index in it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing post, my fault I wasnt clear enough about the output I wanted. Thank you very much for all your help. It will be definitely code I can use again.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '{ a[$1]++; avg[$1]+=$2+$3+$4; sum[$1]+=$5+$6 }
     END{ for(i in a) printf "%s%.2f%s%.2f\n",i OFS,avg[i]/(a[i]*3),OFS,sum[i] }' file
```

The output (the 2nd column - ***average*** value, the 3rd column - ***sum*** value):

```
B5678 0.27 5.14
A1234 0.39 7.88
```

Comment: IMHO, shouldn't be avg[i]/a[i]*3 changed to avg[i]/(a[i]*3) in above code sir, else it will divide them first and then multiple them.